# F-distributions and chi-square distributions: Can someone help explain the answer to this problem?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

> Let $X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4$ be independent $\mathscr{N}(\mu,
>  \sigma^2)$ random variables. Find the distribution of the ratio
>
> $$R=\frac{(X_1-X_2)^2}{(X_3-X_4)^2}.$$
>
> Note that $X_1-X_2$ and $X_3-X_4$ are independent $\mathscr{N}(0,
>  \sigma^2)$ random variables. Thus $W_1=(X_1-X_2)^2/(2\sigma^2)$ and
> $W_2=(X_3-X_4)^2/(2\sigma^2)$ are independent $\mathcal{x}^2(1)$
> random variables. Since $R$ equals $W_1/W_2$, we conclude $R\sim
>  F(1,1).$

I understand that an $F$ distribution is the ratio of two chi-squares with their respective degrees of freedom.  But for this one, why is the square of a non-standard normal distribution a chi-square?  Why is it only one degree of freedom?  Moreover, where does the $2\sigma^2$ come from on the denominators for $W_1$ and $W_2$?

Comment: It would be helpful to edit the title to at least contain the topic of the question. This will attract better answers probably.

Comment: $X_1 - X_2$ is zero mean, it is just that the variance is not necessarily 1.  Thus the square has distribution proportional to a chi-square.

Comment: The $2\sigma^2$ is the factor that would transform your difference into a standard normal and is thus exactly what to multiply a chi-square by to get the distribution of $(X_1-X_2)^2$.

Comment: Ohhh I see it now.  The 0 mean threw me off.  Ok, thank you so much!

Comment: Note that F(1,1) does not have a mean, thus also no variance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $Y_1=X_1-X_2\sim N(0,2\sigma ^2)$ and $Y_2=X_3-X_4\sim N(0,2\sigma ^2)$. We can then normalize these into standard normal random variables: \begin{align*}
Z_1=\frac{X_1-X_2}{2\sigma^2}\sim N(0,1)\\
Z_2=\frac{X_3-X_4}{2\sigma^2}\sim N(0,1)
\end{align*}
Since $Z_1,Z_2$ are standard normal, we can say that $$\frac{Z_1^2}{Z_2^2}\sim F(1,1)$$
So \begin{align*}
\frac{\left(\frac{X_1-X_2}{2\sigma^2}\right)^2}{\left(\frac{X_3-X_4}{2\sigma^2}\right)^2}\sim F(1,1)\\
\frac{(X_1-X_2)^2}{(X_3-X_4)^2}\sim F(1,1)
\end{align*}